# How can I read a top level HashMap from a yamlfile with snakeyaml?

Tags: java, yaml, docker-compose, snakeyaml

I am in the process developing a GUI for a Docker Compose YML file.
Currently I selected snakeyml for reading/writing YML files.

As a test I use the following program (part) to generate a YML file:

```
HashMap<String, Service> map1 = new HashMap();

Service srv1 = new Service();
srv1.setImage("aaa");
srv1.setCommand("-c crc");
List<String> ports = new ArrayList();
ports.add("5001:5001");
ports.add("444:333");
srv1.setPorts(ports);
srv1.setContainer_name("myname");
map1.put("srv1", srv1);

Service srv2 = new Service();
srv2.setImage("bbb");
srv2.setContainer_name("c2");
map1.put("srv2", srv2);

Representer representer = new SkipNullRepresenter();
//comment the following out to remove explicit tags in the YAML file
//representer.addClassTag(Service.class, Tag.MAP);

DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);

Yaml yaml = new Yaml(representer, options);
String output = yaml.dump(map1);
```

Where the Service class is:

```
public class Service {
    private String image = null;
    private String command = null;
    private String container_name = null;
    private List ports = null;

    // plus getters and setters ...
}
```

This gives in my case:

```
srv1: !!CoSession.Service
  command: -c crc
  container_name: myname
  image: aaa
  ports:
  - 5001:5001
  - 444:333
srv2: !!CoSession.Service
  container_name: c2
  image: bbb
```

I can read this back in with:

```
HashMap<String, Service> map2 = new HashMap();
Constructor constructor = new Constructor(map2.getClass());

Yaml yaml2 = new Yaml(constructor);
FileReader reader = new FileReader(f);
map2 = (HashMap<String, Service>)yaml2.load(reader);
```

HOWEVER (where it goes wrong):
When I leave out the tag "!!CoSession.Service" in the YML file, the load does not recognize the block as Service class instance and converts everything to String values. This is now what I want.

I prefer to NOT use the tag. How can I read in a YML like below?
(where all Key-Value pairs under srvX are Service class attributes).

```
srv1:
  command: -c crc
  container_name: myname
  image: aaa
  ports:
  - 5001:5001
  - 444:333
srv2:
  container_name: c2
  image: bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I managed to create the following "Work Around". It works for my case, but a better and more generic solution is appreciated.

I basically override the Constructor class to check on MAP nodes and change them to "Service" nodes when conditions are met.

```
package CoSession;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.Node;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.ScalarNode;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.Tag;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.MappingNode;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.NodeTuple;

import java.util.*;

public class YamlConstructor extends Constructor {

    public YamlConstructor() {
        super();
    }

    public YamlConstructor(Class<? extends Object> theRoot) {
        super(theRoot);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object constructObject(Node node) {
        // Check if this node is actually a Service node, and if so change the tag
        // so that a Java Service object will be instantiated

        //System.out.println("TAG: " + node.getTag().getValue());
        if (node.getTag() == Tag.MAP) {
            // A map is a collection of unsorted key-value pairs in a MappingNode.
            // potentially a Service node
            List<NodeTuple> list = ((MappingNode) node).getValue();

            // scan the collection to check if there is a key that matches the key "image"
            // (this key is required for a Service)
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                NodeTuple nt = list.get(i);
                Node n = nt.getKeyNode();

                // check if the key has the right tag
                if (n.getTag() == Tag.STR) {
                    ScalarNode sn = (ScalarNode) n;
                    if ("image".equals(sn.getValue())) {
                        // All conditions met; we assume this is a Service node!
                        // Now change the tag of the node to Service
                        //System.out.println("***: Changed to Service");

                        node.setTag(new Tag(Service.class));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Use the default constructObject.
        return super.constructObject(node);
    }
}
```